# Passing state through navigation props

Tags: javascript, react-redux, react-native, react-native-navigation

Can someone explain me why this doesn't work as I expect to. I'm trying to navigate from a screen to another using react navigation and I want to pass a value from state from a screen to another (I keep my value from state in parent component and also my 2 functions that changes the state value). When I navigate to my child component, I pass value from state and both functions as well.

The main problem is that I don't see any changes on the child screen when I trigger the 2 functions, but when I go back to my parent screen, the changes have been made and they are visible on the screen.

I've tried to use `this.forceUpdate()` but it is still not working.

Any help?

This is my parent component where I keep the state and the functions that change my state

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableHighlight, Image, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 2
    };
  }

  incrementValue = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1
    }));
  };

  decrementValue = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value - 1
    }));
  };

  onPressButton = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Child', {
      value: this.state.value,
      incrementValue: this.incrementValue.bind(this),
      decrementValue: this.decrementValue.bind(this)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>parent component</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressButton()}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>go to child</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text>state value : {this.state.value}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And here this is my child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableHighlight, Image, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onPressIncrement = () => {
    this.props.navigation.state.params.incrementValue();
    this.forceUpdate();
  };

  onPressDecrement = () => {
    this.props.navigation.state.params.decrementValue();
    this.forceUpdate();
  };

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const value = navigation.getParam('value');
    alert(value);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Child component</Text>
        <Text>{value}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressIncrement()}>
          <Text>incrementValue</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressDecrement()}>
          <Text>decrementValue</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. You just render your `value` prop only in first call of `Child` screen.

There is a lifecycle method named `ComponentDidUpdate` for your prop changes. It is triggered once one of your prop changes.

For example you can use like this in your `Child Screen`,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const value = navigation.getParam('value');
  console.log('prevProps', prevProps);
  console.log('new value', value);
}
```

You should see if value state changes in `Parent Screen` (which you passed as prop to your `Child Screen`) then `ComponentDidUpdate` should triggered with new value.

**Edit:**
After triggered `componentDidUpdate` and access new value. You can use `setState` for trigger render function.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: navigation.getParam('value');
    }
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const value = navigation.getParam('value');
  this.setState({ value });
}

render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Child component</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressIncrement()}>
          <Text>incrementValue</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressDecrement()}>
          <Text>decrementValue</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Well, you are right, when I want to increment/decrement the value, it does trigger the componentDidUpdate() function, but for some reason the value remains the same even after the function was triggered :(

Comment: Yeah, you can re-render it by using `setState` method. Check my edited answer above @Prutii35

Comment: Ugh, still not working, did you tried it by any chance?

Comment: As an alternative to `getParam`, you may use `this.props.navigation.state.params`. @Prutii35